# C# for Windows driver creation?

Tags: c#, device-driver

**Exact Duplicate:** [C# driver development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75886/c-driver-development)

I was wondering whether C# can be used for Windows driver creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see: [C# driver development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75886/c-driver-development)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it -- managed code requires the .NET runtime to execute.