# Sound device emulation in .NET

Tags: .net, audio

What is the simplest way to emulate a sound device in .NET?

Comment: What does it mean to emulate a sound device?

Comment: @Gabe: To make it a fake sound device which appears under the windows sound settings, etc but sends audio IO to the application instead of to an actual device

Comment: If you want your emulator to show up in the Windows sound settings, it has to be a device driver. You cannot write it in .NET.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing drivers in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994600/writing-drivers-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a [User-Mode driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463294.aspx) using COM/.Net interop... but you will probably be in for a world of hurt.