# How to run a driver (.sys file) in Windows using C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, driver

I'm developing a Windows Application using C#. I wanted to run a .sys file (driver basically) at the backEnd as my Code makes use of certain functions to implement the output.

How can i write a code in C# ? If the .sys file is placed in "Bin" folder, it just does not run as I guess it can be made to run as a service.

Consider the name - `"someDriver.sys"` (I'm using Win7 OS here)

Can I run this .sys file as Service in Kernel mode? 
My application is a very simple one and does not have installer (I do not want to have it too). Can you pl help how I can tackle this situation where I need the presence of .sys file for my functions to work.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve, but note that [you cannot write Windows drivers in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1001836/21567) (or any other managed language).

Comment: Basically, in my Windows application, I'm trying to import a .DLL (designed in C++) to achieve some functionality. But this particular DLL wants me to have a driver (.sys file) present and running and that I can use the functions in the DLL. Hence, the need for me to run the driver at the backend.

Comment: Why not install the driver with your app in an installer package?

Comment: okay. my application is kinda tool where I do not want to have any installer and I've only an .exe (which user double clicks and makes use of the tool)

Comment: That doesn't sound like a service. Do you want an exe that the user double clicks to start, or do you want a service?

Comment: EXE is my application (or tool). My appln has to get my driver(.sys) loaded in order to use its functionality as stated above.

Hence, I decided to run the driver as a SERVICE so that my appln can function properly.Is this wrong?

Comment: You need to pinvoke OpenSCManager, OpenService to check if it is already running, CreateService with SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER if is not, StartService, CloseServiceHandle.

Comment: Hi Hans, Could you pls provide a detailed answer instead of the comment? Thanks

Comment: A driver is not a service. Drivers run in kernel mode. Services run in user mode.

Comment: Raymond - I've edited my query.

Comment: Either way - you're going to need admin permissions to say the least to run such a thing on Win7. If you want to have a 'no-setup' app that's usually a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to see how it's done in this article [How to install driver dynamically or install driver as a service for Windows](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/293900/How-to-install-driver-dynamically-or-install-drive)
You must adapt calls using interop.
Use this tools to help you in Interop definition : [PInvoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1172111/1806873) and just change `SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS` to `SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER` (0x00000001). Then you can just do

```
ServiceInsatller.InstallAndStart("yourServiceName", "Some Description", "C:\path\to\driver.sys");
```

This works for me.