# UMDF Development in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, drivers, umdf

Does anyone know if the current state of Microsoft's UMDF allows for driver development in .NET?

Comment: Email the Guy That Knows: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peterwie/contact.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing drivers in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994600/writing-drivers-in-c-sharp)

Comment: by the looks of it you can use C# if you develop using WinDriver ... but not free and proprietary .... http://www.jungo.com/st/windriver_usb_pci_driver_development_software.html ... as for using UMDF in WDF to do a user-mode driver....well it's all COM based....maybe in theory you could do it. In the Windows 8 Preview DDK...the only example using C# is a "Printer Extension Sample"...which is providing a custom IPrinterExtensionContext ... but that's just probably an extension to a printer driver....not a driver per se. You might be able to create a C++ based wrapper in UMDF which hosts .NET.

Comment: @oleksii - I did see that thread but it is over 3 years old and had ambiguous content.

Comment: http://www.jungo.com/st/support/tech_docs/td10.html ... reference specifically to C# driver development with WinDriver.