# Create virtual camera in C#, Windows 10, to work with Zoom, Skype, browser

Tags: c#, camera, windows-10-universal, directshow, mediacapture

I would like to create a "virtual camera" that can be used with 3rd party apps such as Zoom or Skype, browser etc. In the same way these can work with a virtual camera app such as Snap.

I want to take the feed from the built in webcam on the laptop, make some changes to it e.g. brightness, then be able to select in Zoom, Skype, browser, my edited feed.

So far I have written something as a Universal Windows Platform app that takes the webcam feed, applies my processing to it, and shows it in a window. For that I have used the Windows Media API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.effects?view=winrt-19041

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to take this modified feed and make available to Zoom, Skype, browsers? I've seen a lot of stuff related to DirectShow but nothing that fully makes sense or that has been written in the last 6 or 7 years. What would be the best way to do this in 2020, with C#?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693131/how-to-create-virtual-webcam-in-windows-10)? Also, the comments and answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994600/writing-drivers-in-c-sharp) suggest that a video driver should run in user mode and thus in theory could be written in C#.

Comment: The 10 years old answers are still in good standing. There are a lot of questions on virtual cameras on StackOverflow and around.

Comment: Thanks both for the comments. I guess that is a pointer then that the techniques of 10 years ago are still what you would use today. I have looked at many of the related questions here. Many refer to this link for an example but sadly this link doesn't seem to be live anymore http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads.htm

Comment: The original file you're looking for is here: http://web.archive.org/web/20060917030959/http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads/vcam.zip

Comment: Thanks so much, that's really helpful. I've since managed to find a version written entirely in C#.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437617/DirectShow-Virtual-Video-Capture-Source-Filter-in

However, I've been at a loss as to how to implement this. Can't seem to find how do I just pass a video file (or ideally the laptops built in cam) to this. If any suggestions they are very very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa921406(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN check out this documentation, it's c++ which means you would need to wrap it to managed code