# Kernel mode calls a signed C# method in GAC

Tags: c#, dll, driver, gac

Can I call a signed DLL(placed in the GAC) of a C# project from a Kernel mode driver ?

Comment: I *believe* you can. If you have the memory location, similar to a far jump.

Comment: If we can add the signed DLL as a reference to the Kernel mode Driver project , but not using a memory location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the .NET framework refuses to work in kernel mode. See [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75886/c-driver-development) for a similar question.