# twain driver with xerox workcentre

Tags: c#, c++, twain, image-scanner

this is my first time to post here, i need to create a twain driver to control the scanner in a mpf Workcentre Xerox 3635. i need help about this why the xerox twain drivers don't work properly and are very very restricted. The language is or c/c++ or c#. 
Thank a lot for the replies.

Comment: I like pizza. I hope you do too.

Comment: There was this ubergeek at Stanford who liked to say "I can tell you that, but is that what you really want to know?" What exactly do you want to accomplish with your WorkCentre 3635, and what are the critical constraints (like time, money, OS, language, output format, performance, accuracy, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really (really?) want to (re-)create a TWAIN driver? Really?
Are you really sure? If so, like John suggested, I hope you like pizza - and you're into C (see this topic why you shouldn't use C# for building drivers: [C# driver development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75886/c-driver-development))

If, on the other hand, just want to read and use the device.. my first suggestion would be to forget the whole "TWAIN driver idea" and build some application to use the device.

If you're stuck to TWAIN anyway, you might want to check out one of [these](http://www.componentsource.com/relevance/index.html?q=twain+%2Enet) components.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is be very sure that your TWAIN client application is correct.  In C++, I would download [EZTwain](http://www.dosadi.com/eztwain1.htm) and check the demo application.  For C#, try [DotTwain](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/dottwain) (Disclaimer: I work at Atalasoft).  I would also check Irfanview (free and uses TWAIN for capture)

If you can recreate those problems with another TWAIN client, then I would do an [inspectorTWAIN](http://inspectortwain.com) test. I see a Xerox Workcentre there with a score of 100 out of 100 (but check yours).

http://inspectortwain.com/report.aspx?id=e5eeb5c4-78f2-4579-bc3b-2bee9982489c

InspectorTwain checks the capabilities and makes sure that the driver is self consistent -- meaning, that if it says it can do something, it doesn't report an error when you try to do it, and if it has a property, you can set it and get the value back.  It doesn't check that you can actually scan with the driver (since it's automated against the driver, not the hardware).

If you still think the problem is with the driver, make very sure that you have the latest.

If you have the latest, then I strongly suggest you get a better scanner -- it will be orders of magnitude cheaper than making a driver -- there are many that support TWAIN perfectly.  You can check InspectorTWAIN to make sure it has whatever capability you need.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no Workcentre 3635, there's a Phaser 3635.
2. Check if your software is up to date for that device.