# Kernel level programming with C#

Tags: c#, .net, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# driver development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75886/c-sharp-driver-development)

I would like to know if I can do kernel level programming (on Windows) using `C#` or any other `.NET` language?

Comment: Kernel level programming meaning what?  Device drivers?

Comment: @Chris Shain: yes part of it is Device drivers.

Comment: Though not Windows, this might be of interest to you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_%28operating_system%29

Comment: I think you can't. Take a look at [this][1] article.




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75886/c-sharp-driver-development

Comment: For some driver kinds, you can use a c kernel mode driver that forwards events to a usermode C# program. For example such drivers exist for filesystems.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: +1 for link :)

Comment: Not windows, but you might want to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos_%28operating_system%29 or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_%28operating_system%29 as mentioned by @Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The CLR has user mode dependencies and can't be hosted in kernel mode.

That said, there are 2 more things to consider: one, that if you could satisfy the the CLR dependencies in some way, like providing your own implementations of Kernel32 and User32 and other user mode components, then it is probably at least possible. Two, the language itself could be used to output some other language, like x86 assembly, where this would be possible. You'd have to write the translator and provide BCL type analogs, yourself, though.

Answer (score 0):

No. You should use C, possibly C++.

Comment: C++ isn't a good idea. What if an exception is thrown. C is the answer.

Comment: But it is not possible handle it? maybe using `try {}` and `catch {}`.Anyway,I think better write in C.